# Как правильно задать размеры SVG для фона

Tags: css, css3, html5, svg

Хочу сверстать на `svg` фоновую картинку, внутри самого `svg` будут разные детали. Идея в том, чтобы всю эту конструкцию без проблем можно было бы подогнать под все разрешения и размеры экранов. С мобильными устройствами все понятно, придется несколько по-другому реализовать. Меня интересует именно как правильно реализовать `width="" height=""` самого `svg`  и как правильно подогнать `viewBox="0 0 N N"` ко всей этой конструкции. То что можно `svg` вкладывать `svg`  я в курсе...

В первом примере у нас `viewBox="0 0 600 300"` такой. см второй пример

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 600 300">
<polygon 
points="60,25 140,25 160,60 80,60  " 
style="fill: yellow; fill-opacity:0.5; stroke: black;" />
<polygon points="50,147.5 87.5,120 122.5,147.5 110,190 65,190" 
style="fill: blue; fill-opacity:0.7; stroke: black; " />

<polyline stroke="red" stroke-width="3px" fill="black" 
  points=" 50,80 140,80 80,100 180,100 160,85 160,115 180,100" />
</svg>
```

А вот во  втором примере `viewBox="0 0 1200 700"`  и естественно, дает такую разницу...

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1200 700">
<polygon 
points="60,25 140,25 160,60 80,60  " 
style="fill: yellow; fill-opacity:0.5; stroke: black;" />
<polygon points="50,147.5 87.5,120 122.5,147.5 110,190 65,190" 
style="fill: blue; fill-opacity:0.7; stroke: black; " />

<polyline stroke="red" stroke-width="3px" fill="black" 
  points=" 50,80 140,80 80,100 180,100 160,85 160,115 180,100" />
</svg>
```

Если открыть эти два примера одновременно, мы видим, что у нас при одном и том же размере экрана картинки выглядят по-разному, как сделать, чтобы они выглядели одинаково  и viewBox="0 0 N N" подгонялся на всю ширину экрана?

Знаю, что `width="" height=""` для `svg` можно задать в процентах. А вот  `viewBox="0 0 N N"` можно реализовать в процентах, и как это все грамотно и правильно реализовать?

Comment: `viewBox` в процентах не допускается, только цифровые значения     картинку бы ещё хорошо добавить или можно взять свою? Я правильно понял, что вы хотите один svg использовать в качестве фона, как вы планируете его добавлять? Поверх фона svg будут другие объекты svg?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, ты правильно, вся эта конструкция будет состоять из разных деталей `svg`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Попутно получился пример с множеством использования вложенных svg/
- Многократное использование объектов svg c использованием команды
  `use`, как для вызова группы объектов, так и для вызова отдельных
  частей блока.
- Пример позиционирования объектов внутри вложенных svg

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1200 700">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="greenyellow"  />
  <defs> 
  <desc> Прячем фигуры для дальнейшего многократного использования </desc>
  <g id="block">
  <polygon  id="poly"
  
points="60,25 140,25 160,60 80,60  " 
style="fill: yellow; fill-opacity:0.5; stroke: black;" />

<polygon id="pentagon" points="50,147.5 87.5,120 122.5,147.5 110,190 65,190" 
style="fill: blue; fill-opacity:0.7; stroke: black; " />

<polyline id="zigzag" stroke="red" stroke-width="3px" fill="black" 
  points=" 50,80 140,80 80,100 180,100 160,85 160,115 180,100" /> 
  </g>
  </defs>
  <svg   viewBox="0 0 600 300">
 <desc> Выводим блок фигур с новым viewBox </desc>  
  <use xlink:href="#block" />
</svg >
  <svg viewBox="-100 0 600 300" > 
   <desc> Выводим блок фигур с тем же viewBox но сдвигаем вправо на 100px </desc>  
   <use xlink:href="#block" />
  </svg>    
  
   <svg viewBox="-200 -150 600 300" > 
   <desc> Выводим блок фигур  сдвигаем вправо на 200px и опускаем вниз на 150px </desc> 
   <use xlink:href="#block" />
  </svg>
 <svg viewBox="-400 -150 600 300" > 
 <desc> Выводим только зигзаг  сдвигаем вправо на 400px и опускаем вниз на 150px </desc> 
   <use xlink:href="#zigzag" />
  </svg>  
  
  <svg viewBox="-400 140 600 300" > 
<desc> Выводим только пятиугольник  сдвигаем вправо на 400px и поднимаем на 150px </desc>   
  <use xlink:href="#pentagon" />
  </svg>
  
   <svg viewBox="0 -250 600 300" > 
    <desc> Выводим только Параллелограмм   опускаем на 250px </desc>  
   <use xlink:href="#poly" />
  </svg>
  
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

Может быть Вам подойдёт способ масштабирования с помощью атрибута transform?

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('group1').setAttribute('transform', 'scale(1)')">
1x</button>
<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('group1').setAttribute('transform', 'scale(2)')">
2x</button>
<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('group1').setAttribute('transform', 'scale(3)')">
3x</button>

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('group1').setAttribute('transform', 'scale(4)')">
4x</button>


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1200 700">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="gray"/>
<g id="group1">
<polygon 
points="60,25 140,25 160,60 80,60  " 
style="fill: yellow; fill-opacity:0.5; stroke: black;" />
<polygon points="50,147.5 87.5,120 122.5,147.5 110,190 65,190" 
style="fill: blue; fill-opacity:0.7; stroke: black; " />

<polyline stroke="red" stroke-width="3px" fill="black" 
  points=" 50,80 140,80 80,100 180,100 160,85 160,115 180,100" />
  </g>
</svg>
</html>
```

[Вот здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?p=5) разбираются на пальцах вопросы масштабирования.
И [вот здесь](http://xiper.net/learn/svg/svg-essentials/the-scale-transformation).

Comment: Очень информативно:)

Comment: Пожалуйста, публикуйте ссылки в качестве дополнения к вашему ответу, а не вместо него. После изменения или удаления материалов по ссылке ваш ответ в нынешней редакции не будет иметь смысла.

Comment: @tutankhamun Вас понял.

Comment: @MindCleaner, уж лучше виртуальную область просмотра менять(viewBox), чем делать увеличение с помощью `transform`. Но, как вариант вполне подходит

Comment: @MindCleaner, заходи в чат   https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat

Comment: @Air Возможно не хватает репутации, чтобы ответить в чате.

Answer (score 3):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1200 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%"/>
    <rect width="97%" height="97%" x="15" y="10" fill="gray"/>
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 600 300">
      <polygon points="60,25 140,25 160,60 80,60 " style="fill: yellow; fill-opacity:0.5; stroke: black;" />
      <polygon points="50,147.5 87.5,120 122.5,147.5 110,190 65,190" style="fill: blue; fill-opacity:0.7; stroke: black; " />
      <polyline stroke="red" stroke-width="3px" fill="black" points=" 50,80 140,80 80,100 180,100 160,85 160,115 180,100" />
    </svg>

</svg>
```